# Firebase Messaging Not Sending Data-Only Notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to have my app adjust the data of a notification, before sending it to the notification tray.  I am using Firebase Messaging to send notifications.  The goal is to receive the data packet, format it (pulling local info in as well), then create a notification.  This needs to happen when app is in background / killed.

Note.  In some configurations discussed below, I am able to do this when the app is in the foreground, which isn't very useful for encouraging someone to open the app.

My local FirebaseMessagingService.  This is called effectively when app is in foreground (I have confirmed with logging functions), when data is received.  It does not run when app is in background.

```
class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    private val keyCategory1 = "category1key"
    private val keyCategory1 = "category2key"

    private fun generateNotification(title: String, message: String, badgeNumber: Int) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0, arrayOf(intent), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        val channelID = "channel_id"
        val channelName = "channel_name"

        var builder : NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext,channelID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setNumber(badgeNumber)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000,250,1000))
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        builder = builder.setContent(getRemoteView(title,message))

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

        notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build())
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {

        if(message.notification != null) {
            var msgTitle = "DEFAULT MESSAGE TITLE"
            var msgBody = "Default notification body text"

            for (doc in message.data) {
                when (doc.key) {
                    "someKey" -> { var1 = doc.value }
                    "someOtherKey" -> { var2 = doc.value }
                    "category" -> { notifyCategory = doc.value }
                    "badge" -> { badgeNumber = parseInt(doc.value) }
                }
            }

            if (notifyCategory == keyCategory1) {
                // format message and title one way using var1
                // pull data from local RoomDB to personalize display
            } else if (notifyCategory == keyCategory2) {
                // format message and title a different way using var2
            }
            generateNotification(msgTitle,msgBody,badgeNumber)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout")
    fun getRemoteView(title: String, body: String) : RemoteViews {
        val remoteView = RemoteViews("com.package.name",R.layout.notification)
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, title)
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_body, body)
        remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_image,R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        return remoteView
    }
```

From my firebase function I have tried multiple formats.  The most success I've had is this format, but the notification title and body are displayed, not the locally adjusted titles that are needed.  Also the data management is only called if app is in foreground, not in background.  Apparently this is the expected behavior for a message payload of this format:

```
const payload = {
        "token": userFCMtoken,
        "notification": {
          "body": "Serverside message body",
          "title": "Serverside message title",
        },
        "data": {
          "category": "category1key",
          "someKey": someValue,
        },
```

Per other answers here, if you remove the 'notification' block, then the app is supposed to take over and run onMessageReceived, regardless of app state.  I reformatted my output to the following.  However, this does not work.  Data is not received by the app, in foreground or background none of the logs operate, and no notification is created.

```
const payload = {
        "token": userFCMtoken,
        "data": {
          "category": "category1key",
          "someKey": someValue,
        },
```

Does anyone know why it suddenly wouldn't receive any information?  My Firebase function logs online suggest that the message was sent.  But I cannot receive it.

Any other ways to have local onMessageReceive intercept and modify a notification before sending it to the notification tray?

Comment: It seems that you are not providing a `notification` payload meaning it is `null` but you are still checking `if (message.notification != null)`, did you mean to use `if (message.data != null)`?

Comment: @DarShan that's a good catch.  I made that update, but still onMessageReceived() is not triggered when sending the second data packet

Comment: I have also tried adding the key value pair "priority": "high" with out any success